# question on textbook activity using ～ば～ほど

Tags: usage

We are using the textbook "Adventures in Japanese," and in class we got up to this activity:

> Begin a conversation with your partner with the comments below. Your partner agrees, then gives his/her opinion starting with でも and using the ～ば～ほど pattern.

Example as written:

> 質問： 数学って、むずかしいね。
>   答え：ええ。でも、勉強すればするほど、分かるようになるよ。
>
> １．質問：漢字って、むずかしいね。

We spent like 15-20 minutes in class trying to figure out an answer that works: our sensei says there is something wrong no matter how many times we try to answer that we aren't realizing.
How I tried to answer:

> ええ。でも、勉強すればするほど新聞が読めるようになるよ。

other questions:

> 日本語って、むずかしいね。
>   お茶って、苦いね。
>   茶道って、つまらないね。

Any insight? Thank you.

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Asking what may possibly be wrong, or if you could suggest responses to the questions using the ～ば～ほど pattern

Answer (score 3):

ほど is a word used to express degree. On the other hand, 読める is almost binary, if not otherwise qualified (either you can read, or you can't). Your answer seems to fall into this--either you can read the newspaper, or you can't. A newspaper is kind of a baseline thing (restricted character usage, style), and it feels like it would be all-or-nothing in English or Japanese. I agree with your teacher that something feels wrong.

How about these?

> A: 漢字って、難しいね。
>
> B: たしかに。でも、勉強すればするほど、漢字の奥深さが見えてくるよ？

-

> A: お茶って、苦いね。
>
> B: まあ、そうだけど、飲めば飲むほど、お茶の独特な味がわかるようになると思う。

-

> A: 茶道って、つまらないね。
>
> B: よく言われる。でも、練習すればするほど、なんだか、落ち着いていくんだ。

Comment: Hmm, I'm not confident about the use of ～ていく in the last sentence.

Comment: 「てくる」を使って、「気持ちが落ち着いて*くる*よ」とか、どうでしょうか。

Comment: 最初にそう思ったんですけども、茶道と長い付き合いのBさんのことじゃなくて、素人のAさんのことを指しているのなら、「～ていく」の方が適切のではと思えてきたのです。そのような使い方って、可能ですか？…それも結局Aさんが茶道を学べば学ぶほど、Bさんへ近づいて*くる*ことになりますけどね。